# Easiest way to reset Backbone's model to initial defaults?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

My models already have a `defaults` hash. When parts of the view/page are reset, I wish to reset the models back to their original defaults.

Currently, I explicitly set each attribute to its default value. Is there anything built in or a JavaScript/Underscore.js/Backbone.js/jQuery function that I could use to do this in a single statement?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
myModel.clear().set(myModel.defaults);
```

Comment: Haaaaaaaaaa! Knew it would this simple!!! Thanks :) I can't believe I overlooked this :)

Comment: This is kinda dangerous though, because if you didn't specify {id: null} in your defaults, it will have the same id as before and using save() will PUT it to the server, overwriting the old object in the server with default values!

Comment: If you want a completely different model, construct a new one: `myModel = new MyModel()`.

Comment: True, but it's useful to use the same object if others are bound to it.

Comment: **Note:** Any properties that are not listed in `defaults` will *not* be cleared from the model. You'll probably want to call [`.clear()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clear) first.

Comment: One problem I'm having with this approach is that the 'change' event only fires once, before the defaults have been set.

Comment: you can use `{silent:true}` as the parameter for the clear to prevent the change event from firing

Answer (score 6):

I came up with the following approach:

```
reset: function () {
    this.clear({silent: true});
    this.set(this.defaults);
}
```

Having `{silent: true}` in the `clear()` call ensures that the `change` event is not fired; it will be fire only on `set()` call.

Answer (score 5):

I do this when the model has non-null initial object properties.

first, define **defaults** as a function

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extends({

    defaults:function(){

        return {
            AnArrayTypeProp:[]
        };
    }

});
```

second, when needed to reset model to default

```
model.clear().set(model.defaults());
```

Comment: Use `_.result(model, 'defaults`)` to handle both an object or a function `defaults` property.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [saabeilin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36610475/1218980)'s answer and [Backbone's annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html), I came with an optimal function to fill the need for resetting a model.

## Reusable reset

```
/**
 * Clears the model's attributes and sets the default attributes.
 * @param  {Object} attrs to overwrite defaults
 * @param  {Object} options  to pass with the "set" call.
 * @return {Backbone.Model}  this object, to chain function calls.
 */
reset: function(attrs, options) {
    // adds default option reset to true
    options = _.extend({ reset: true }, options);

    // ensure default params
    var defaults = _.result(this, 'defaults');
    attrs = _.defaults(_.extend({}, defaults, attrs), defaults);

    // apply
    this.clear({ silent: true }).set(attrs, options);

    // triggers a custom event, namespaced to model in order
    // to avoid collision with collection's native reset event
    // when listening to a collection.
    if (!options.silent) this.trigger('model:reset', this, options);

    return this;
},
```

The following line ensures that even if an attribute is passed as undefined `{ test: undefined }`, it'll still have its default value.

```
attrs = _.defaults(_.extend({}, defaults, attrs), defaults);
```

Here's an example:

```
var defaults = { test: 1 }, 
    attrs = { test: undefined };

_.extend({}, defaults, attrs);                       // {test: undefined}
_.defaults(_.extend({}, defaults, attrs), defaults); // {test: 1}
```

## Extending Backbone

And if you want it with all Backbone models, you can extend Backbone itself:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, {
    reset: function(attributes, options){
        /* ... */
    }
});
```

<sup>*Disclaimer: Don't do this if you're writing a JavaScript lib or Backbone plugin, as it could collide with another lib or it could cause a different behavior than the one expected by the person using your code.*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I also thought about using `model.clear()` and `model.set()` in conjunction. Then I ran across the problem, that I trigger the `change` event twice now.
Using the `silent` option when calling `model.clear()` is not an option, because I also want to have a `change` event fired, when a property gets unset.

I ended up with adding a `model.reset()` method. It takes a new attributes hash and fills this hash with `undefined` values for old attributes keys not being present in the new attribute hash.

```
Model.prototype.reset = function(attrs, options) {
    for (var key in this.attributes) {
        if (key in attrs) continue;
        attrs[key] = void 0;
    }

    return this.set(attrs, options);
};
```

This way you reset the models old attributes and get a valid `change` event for every old and new attribute.

Comment: This code doesn't deal with Model.prototype.changedAttributes()

Comment: To deal with the lack of event when unsetting with `model.clear({silent: true})`, [I trigger a custom event `model:reset`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36685283/1218980).

Answer (score 1):

What about overriding the value of current model with a new empty model :

```
myModel = new model(); // default values will be considered
```

Comment: This works, but it will destroy any events bound to the model. If I have a `change` event on `myModel` and I overwrite it like this, a) it will not fire a change event, and b) any previously bound events would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

My solutions is:

```
model.clear({silent: true}).set(model.defaults);
```